# I want to read and decode PDF-417 barcodes within a .NET application

Tags: decode, barcode-scanner, motorola, pdf417

Is there any method exposed in MOTOROLA DS9208 scanner dll/api to decode the PDF-417 barcodes.
Device Name:- Motorola Scanner 
Device Model Number:- DS9208

Answer (score 1):

By default, Pdf417 is readable on the MOTOROLA(currently Zebra) DS9208.
However, MicroPDF417 is in Disable state by default, so read the setting barcode and enable it if necessary.
[DS9208 DIGITAL SCANNER PRODUCT REFERENCE GUIDE](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/barcode-scanners/ds9208-prg-en.pdf)
Pgae 274  10 - 84 DS9208 Product Reference Guide

SDK (including various documents / drivers) can be downloaded from the following page.
[DS9208 HANDS-FREE IMAGER SUPPORT](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/scanners/general-purpose-scanners/ds9208.html)

The standardized API materials / libraries are the same as in the previous article.
[I want to read and decode PDF-417 barcodes stored in an image or PDF file from within a .NET application [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61664532/9014308)